# Typescript is not infering type correctly when used with generic interface

Tags: typescript

Here is my code :

```
import {FieldType} from '/imports/common/core/schema/Schema';

interface Content<S, F extends keyof S> {
  name: F
  type: FieldType | Container<S[F]>
}

class Container<S> {
  content: Content<S, keyof S>;

  constructor(content: Content<S, keyof S>) {
    this.content = content;
  }
}

type Parent = {
  height: number
};

type Child = {
  age: number
  parent: Parent
}

const containerParent = new Container<Parent>({
  name: 'height',
  type: FieldType.String
});

new Container<Child>({
  name: 'parent',
  type: containerParent // This line fails....
});
```

You can try it here :

[Exemple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtwXAHgMoA0yAYshAB6QgAmAzsgNYQCe6MyeAfMgN4BQyZCDgBbCAC4SA5GGYAHCclpgooAObIAPmkxg4oaPgDaxALqc+AXz58EAGzi16GcPpCGuvaQl3YwklyowfCImVnYuAG4bQR8QZSgAVwQwdCgACjiggN9cQkYWNg5OAEovQUEwAAtgWgA6LL9kAF5kRvBowWtrPlkFZAAFOCgm1v5BKohgNSr-IUSRACNoK2je+RRUGrtqFvLkODVFEAXlqGk5Yb9JIZHwKxs45TbdN2hb0aEIAHcdVwMoDgPuBOOlxkJRIoAOSTaazKEEaR9aHfKpwSAAN2gUKsJTW7l+gTegK2wB2oPBwjEkihlzuYARSI2kiyxOBYFxkSAA)

I want to know how I could make TS to infer that the value I want the "type" property to expect to receive a Container, because I set the name to 'parent' the line before. For now it waits for a Container<number | Parent>...

Edit:

[Updated exemple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=19&pln=28&pc=27#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCYB4DKANGshAB6QjYDOyA1hAJ4D2My+AfMgN4BQyyEHAC2EAFxp+yAG5xMAV3HJqYKKADmyAD7sEACwjC4BANqoAuh14BfXrwSY41Wvn2HjREuUo16TVuzIALx+LGycPFIwGDjUEuhYeJ6oHCbmANx2AgjMICpQ8ghgzFAAFNGJcWgxScQpaQCUkQICYHrA1AB0FbHByD00mQK2trxgjAAOKAAKcFAQ4H18AgbA6npgEiDywgBG0DaZY5MoAMLtOEtScOpK23sHAhNzC5vIs-PgNnY5eWDIvzAcFA0A+rz6IAgAHddAYjLgweAOKUTMtBCIlAByVbrMCYwhSWQKLFQvRwSDSaCYmzmBpHSEw1xw4znYA4YiY56fPHI1FSISiCScl7gfGEuSKCSA4GQqCIsA2YhogVYm4QMUCImS5AARgATDS6UA)

Comment: `containerParent` isn't a type, it's a value. You can use [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to get the type of a value: `type: typeof containerParent`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Content` is based on a specific key of `S`, but `Container` uses all keys of `S` for its type instead of any specific key.  So the `type` of the constructor argument is expected to be `string | Container<S[keyof S]>`.

The errors go away if you change `Container` to take a second generic for the key.  You can make that second variable optional and have default to `keyof S` so that you don't need to change `Container<Parent>`.

```
class Container<S, F extends keyof S = keyof S> {
  content: Content<S, F>;

  constructor(content: Content<S, F>) {
    this.content = content;
  }
}
```

With the current setup, you do have to set the key generic on the child container for it to work.  You can't tell typescript to infer the second type while explicitly setting the first.

```
new Container<Child, 'parent'>({
  name: 'parent',
  type: containerParent
});
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/AwQd1W)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't completely resolve my problem though but I didn't ask it very clearly at the beginning. I'm actually impressed that you understood it at all. My problem is that in the real life issue I'm trying to resolve with this basic example the Container constructor receives an array.

Actually, I want to create a schema to meta document my objects. I updated my example to make it clearer. 

`
new Schema<Child, 'parent'>([{
  name: 'parent',
  value: containerParent
}, {
  name: 'age',
  value: 12
}]);`

Comment: I updated my question with a link to my second exemple. The thing is, I'd like TS to sort out by himself the type of the 'value' field from the type of the property with the name set on the 'name' field.